# Is this exercise correct?

Tags: limits

I found this exercise in a textbook:

Let $f$ be the function defined by
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{1-x}+x^2+ax+bx}{x^2-2x+1}$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

(a) If the limit $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ is a real number, then show that $a=b=-1.$

(b) Calculate the above limit, if you know that it is a real number.

But the above limit for $a=b=-1$ yields
$$\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=+\infty$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=-\infty$$

Comment: Are you sure that it’s “$ax+bx$”? That seems strange, as that could just as easily be written as $(a+b)x$. Could it be that it’s $ax+b$ instead?

Comment: Is there a typo? if $a=b=-1$ works, then why not $a=-2$ and $b=0$?

Comment: (assuming ax+b) Can you show your working for calculating those 2 limits as x approaches 1? I agree that the denominator is 0, but so is the numerator. I calculate that the limits are non-zero and finite.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly like that in the text book!

Comment: Your book does appear to have a typo. It is best to assume that the expression in numerator is $ax+b$ instead of $ax+bx$ and proceed by putting $t=1-x$.

Answer (score 1):

when $a=b=-1$
$$  f(x)=\frac{e^{1-x}+x^2-2x}{x^2-2x+1}  $$
expanding $e^{x-1}$ around $x=1$  You get $  f(x) \sim 1+(1-x)+\frac 12 (1-x)^2$
 we  have $$\lim_{x \to 1}  f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1}  \left(  1+\frac{(1-x)+\frac 12 (1-x)^2}{x^2-2x+1} \right)  
 \\ =  \lim_{x \to 1}  \left(  \frac32+\frac{ 1}{1-x} \right)  $$
 which is clearly not going to be finite.
One thing that does occur to me is that 
$$ \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{e^{(1-x)^2}+x^2-2x}{x^2-2x+1} =2 $$

But perhaps more to the point, if you consider that $(ax+b) $ is intended instead of $ax+bx$, then we get fro $a=b=-1$

$$\lim_{x \to 1}  f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1}  \left(  \frac{ x^2-x-1+1+(1-x)  + \frac 12 (1-x)^2}{x^2-2x+1} \right)  
 \\ =  \frac 32 $$

My guess is that is what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise is clearly wrong as you might be able to determine $a+b$ but you have no information on how to separate $a$ and $b$.  It is a harder exercise to guess what the question was and solve it.  Initially, I would guess that one of the terms should have a power on the $x$.  We need the numerator to cancel the two factors of $x-1$ in the denominator for the limit to be finite.  Initially, I would guess the $bx$ term should be $bx^2$

As $x \to 1, e^{1-x} \to 1-(x-1)+\frac 12(x-1)^2+O(x-1)^3=\frac 52+\frac 12x^2+O(x-1)^3$.Ignoring the $(x-1)^3$ term we then have 
$$f(x)=\frac{\frac 52+\frac 12x^2+x^2+ax+bx^2}{x^2-2x+1}$$
The constant terms force the ratio to be $\frac 52$ so we would need $a=-5,b=2$  Because this is so different from the book solution, I would think my guess at a correction is incorrect.  I leave this because it helps thinking about these problems.  It doesn't work to have it be $a+bx$, either.

Answer (score 0):

To work on this problem,
I apply my motto 
"always have limits go to zero."

If
$f(x)
=\dfrac{e^{1-x}+x^2+ax+bx}{x^2-2x+1}
=\dfrac{e^{1-x}+x^2+(a+b)x}{(x-1)^2}
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(1+y)
&=\dfrac{e^{1-(1+y)}+(1+y)^2+(a+b)(1+y)}{(1+y-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-y}+(1+2y+y^2)+a+b+(a+b)y}{y^2}\\
&=\dfrac{1-y+y^2/2+(1+2y+y^2)+a+b+(a+b)y}{y^2}\\
&=\dfrac{1-y+y^2/2+O(y^3)+(1+2y+y^2)+a+b+(a+b)y}{y^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2+a+b+y(1+a+b)+3y^2/2+O(y^3)}{y^2}\\
\end{array}
$

For the limit as $y \to 0$
to be finite,
we must have
$a+b = -2$
and $a+b = -1$,
which is impossible.

So,
I'll change the problem.

If
$f(x)
=\dfrac{e^{1-x}+x^2+ax+b}{x^2-2x+1}
=\dfrac{e^{1-x}+x^2+ax+b}{(x-1)^2}
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(1+y)
&=\dfrac{e^{1-(1+y)}+(1+y)^2+a(1+y)+b}{(1+y-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-y}+(1+2y+y^2)+a+b+ay}{y^2}\\
&=\dfrac{1-y+y^2/2+O(y^3)+(1+2y+y^2)+a+b+ay}{y^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2+a+b+y(1+a)+3y^2/2+O(y^3)}{y^2}\\
\end{array}
$

For this limit to exist,
we must have
$a+b = -2$
and
$1+a = 0$
so $a = -1$
and
$b = -1$.

The fraction is then
$\dfrac{3y^2/2+O(y^3)}{y^2}
=\dfrac32 + O(y)
\to \dfrac32
$.